# Ускорение луп кода на Python 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется данный код :

```
def filter(A,B):
[NAx, NAy, NAz] = np.shape(A);
   [NBx, NBy, NBz] = np.shape(B);
   Deg = NAz + NBz -1;
   C = np.zeros((NAx,NBy,Deg));
   for n in range(0,(Deg)):
     for m in range(0,n+1):
       if ((n-m)<NAz and m<NBz):
         C[:,:,n] = C[:,:,n] + np.dot(A[:,:,(n-m)],B[:,:,m]);
   print(n)
   print(m)
   return C
```

Как можно его ускорить? При добавлении модуля Numba, длительность становится еще дольше.

Comment: А что делает код?

Comment: Используется в качестве алгоритма MDCT на Python.
умножает две полиномиальные матрицы (массивы) A и B, где каждый элемент матрицы является полиномом.
Эти полиномиальные записи находятся в 3-м измерении
Третье измерение также можно интерпретировать как содержащее (2D) коэффициент
показатель z^-1.
Результат C=A*B;

Comment: Добавьте в в вопрос небольшой пример данных.